# Creating an Outlook Addin with Visual Studio 2013 (Using ItemSend)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, outlook, outlook-addin

I want a simple addin for outlook, that asks the user before he sends an email. Actually my code compiles but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea?

Thanks

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application
Event ItemSend As AssemblyLoadEventHandler

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    myOlApp = Me.Application
End Sub

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    Initialize_handler()
End Sub

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown

End Sub

Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim prompt As String
    prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"
    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Does your code get executed? Can you put a breakpoint and have VS stop in there fucntions?

Comment: No myOlApp_ItemSend doesn't execute. Tha last breakpoint is: "myOlApp = Me.Application"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declaration of myOlApp_ItemSend must include "Handles":

```
Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles myOlApp.ItemSend
```

Comment: pretty sure I have the same issue, but it says that the signatures (`Public Sub` and `Private Event` do not have a compatible signature, which seems evident, but I'm not sure where I need to change things(?)

Comment: ah - nevermind, me thinks I simply had a byval on Cancel instead of a byref... ah, inherited code...